# Dividing with variable that could be zero

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have an expression :
$\ r^2 = r\cos(x)$.

I want to express $\ r$ as a function of $\ x $.

both $\cos(x)$ and $\ r$ can be zero, but only if $\cos(x) = r = 0$ .

Is it then valid to "remove" one $\ r$ like this ? :

$\ r = \cos(x)$

Answer (score 0):

You can write $$r^2=r\cos(x)$$ as $$r(r\cos(x))=0$$

Comment: Thanks!      However, do you mean r(r - cosx) = 0? That makes sense since r - cosx = 0 would be a solution equivalent to r = cosx.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i mean!